# Angular: How to parse JSON variables into SCSS

Tags: json, angular, sass, angular9, node-sass-json-importer

Within an Angular application, I do D3 visuals through either plain [D3](https://d3js.org/) or [Vega](https://vega.github.io/vega/). There's also SCSS styling going on.

I'd like to be able to refer to the same global variables for styling from Javascript and from SCSS. JSON files do the trick very well for storing settings that I load into Typescript through a simple `import` statement. But how does one go about doing the same from SCSS ?

`node-sass-json-importer` seems like a good candidate but adding it to an Angular 9 CLI application isn't obvious to me.

[This StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41261016/integrate-node-sass-json-importer-into-an-angular-cli-application) brushed on the topic a while back, but it involved modifying resources under `node_modules` which is hardly sustainable.

There are also some inputs in the orginal doc as to [how one can go about tweaking webpack in a non-Angular app](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-sass-json-importer#webpack--sass-loader). I do not know how to relate this to an Angular app built through the CLI.

> Webpack / sass-loader 
>   Blockquote
>
> Webpack v1

```
import jsonImporter from 'node-sass-json-importer';

// Webpack config
export default {
  module: {
    loaders: [{
      test: /\.scss$/,
      loaders: ["style", "css", "sass"]
    }],
  },
  // Apply the JSON importer via sass-loader's options.
  sassLoader: {
    importer: jsonImporter()
  }
};
```

> Webpack v2

```
import jsonImporter from 'node-sass-json-importer';

// Webpack config
export default {
  module: {
    rules: [
      test: /\.scss$/,
      use: [
        'style-loader',
        {
          loader: 'css-loader',
          options: {
            importLoaders: 1
          },
        },
        {
          loader: 'sass-loader',
          // Apply the JSON importer via sass-loader's options.
          options: {
            importer: jsonImporter(),
          },
        },
      ],
    ],
  },
};
```

Comment: Maybe this an option? https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular-builders/custom-webpack

Comment: Does this help? https://github.com/vigetlabs/sass-json-vars

Comment: it seems to relate to node-sass-json-importer but my remaining challenge would be getting this to work in an Angular 9 CLI app

Comment: I haven't downvoted anything. Anyone can downvote, not just the OP.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do it without changing any `node_modules` files by using [`@angular-builders/custom-webpack`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular-builders/custom-webpack) to setup custom Webpack rules and as you mention [`node-sass-json-importer`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-sass-json-importer) to import JSON files inside SCSS files.

You'll have to install [`node-sass`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-sass) for the `implementation` option because [`node-sass-json-importer`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-sass-json-importer) is compatible with [`node-sass`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-sass).

1. Install packages [`@angular-builders/custom-webpack`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular-builders/custom-webpack), [`node-sass-json-importer`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-sass-json-importer) and [`node-sass`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-sass):

   ```
   npm i -D @angular-builders/custom-webpack node-sass-json-importer node-sass
   ```
2. Create Webpack config file (`webpack.config.js`) to the project root directory with the following contents:

   ```
   const jsonImporter = require('node-sass-json-importer');

   module.exports = {
     module: {
       rules: [{
         test: /\.scss$|\.sass$/,
         use: [
           {
             loader: require.resolve('sass-loader'),
             options: {
               implementation: require('node-sass'),
               sassOptions: {
                 // bootstrap-sass requires a minimum precision of 8
                 precision: 8,
                 importer: jsonImporter(),
                 outputStyle: 'expanded'
               }
             },
           }
         ],
       }],
     },
   }
   ```
3. Change `builder` to `@angular-builders/custom-webpack:[architect-target]` and add `customWebpackConfig` option to `build`, `serve` and `test` build targets inside `angular.json`:

   ```
   "projects": {
     ...
     "[project]": {
       ...
       "architect": {
         "build": {
           "builder: "@angular-builders/custom-webpack:browser",
           "options": {
             "customWebpackConfig": {
               "path": "webpack.config.js"
             },
             ...
           },
           ...
         },
         "serve": {
           "builder: "@angular-builders/custom-webpack:dev-server",
           "customWebpackConfig": {
             "path": "webpack.config.js"
           },
           ...
         },
         "test": {
           "builder: "@angular-builders/custom-webpack:karma",
           "customWebpackConfig": {
             "path": "webpack.config.js"
           },
           ...
         },
       },
       ...
     },
     ...
   }
   ```

Now you can include any `.json` file inside any component `.scss` file:

#### `hello-world.component.scss`:

```scss
@import 'hello-world.vars.json';

.hello-bg {
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: $bg-color;
  border: 2px solid $border-color;
}
```

#### `hello-world.vars.json`:

```json
{
  "bg-color": "yellow",
  "border-color": "red"
}
```

I have created a Github repository with all these working that you can clone and test from here: https://github.com/clytras/angular-json-scss

```bash
git clone https://github.com/clytras/angular-json-scss.git
cd angular-json-scss
npm install
ng serve
```

Answer (score 3):

Another option is to use `raw-loader`, it is available by default in angular-cli. This way you can load raw scss file into ts component:

```
// Adding `!!` to a request will disable all loaders specified in the configuration
import scss from '!!raw-loader!./config.scss';

console.info('scss', scss);
```

You have to declare module in `.d.ts` file:

```
declare module '!!raw-loader!./*.scss';
```

Then you can extract any information you want.

So instead of loading JSON into scss you can load scss into ts.

Comment: This worked for me, but I found it a bit hard to follow. Please provide example file names for the declared module (.d.ts) and style sheet (.scss). It would also be helpful if you provided some example .scss code and how you would access it. I was able to use regular expressions, but a more complicated .scss file might be harder to target like that.

Answer (score 2):

I have a relatively simple approach for you:

Separate the `node-sass` step form the `ng build` step and use the generated `.css` files instead of the `sass` files in your angular app.

This has two advantages:

- no need to heavily tweak and edit any node-modules
- full control over how the sass is compiled

For the implementation i would go ahead as follows:

1. add `./node_modules/.bin/node-sass --importer node_modules/node-sass-json-importer/dist/cli.js --recursive ./src --output ./src` to the scripts in your `package.json` e.g. with the name `build-sass`. You can tweak this command to only include the sass files that you need the recursive mode for (make sure to ignore them in the angular.json, so they don't get compiled twice).
2. run the command once `npm run build-sass` in order to generate the `.css` files in the project.
3. change references in angular components where needed from the `.sass` to `.css`
4. (optionally) add a convenience command `npm run build-sass && ng build` as `compile` in your package.json which you can run whenever you want to build the whole project.

While this approach is relatively simple, it comes with a few drawbacks

- for any components where you want to use the css, the hot-reload feature of `ng serve` will require you to run your `npm run build-sass` to see any changes you made to your styles in real-time
- your project will look a bit messier, as there are `.scss` and `.css` files for the same component in the `/src` folder of which the `.css` is generated. You will need to make sure (e.g. by adding a suffix or comment) that noone accidentally edits the generated `.css` and those changes get overridden.

Other approaches would almost always involve heavily editing existing or writing your own webpack compiler.

Answer (score 1):

Working in angular 10:
Use custom webpack as others have mentioned, but the only working way i could get to work in angular 10 was editing a function, originally suggested by [Kishorevarma](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56349663).

webpack.config.js

```
const jsonImporter = require("node-sass-json-importer");

const webpack = require("webpack");

const mode =
  process.env.NODE_ENV === "production" ? "production" : "development";

module.exports = function (config) {
  const rules = config.module.rules || [];
  rules.forEach((rule) => {
    if (String(rule.test) === String(/\.scss$|\.sass$/)) {
      const loaders = rule.use;
      const transformedLoaders = loaders.map((l) => {
        if (l.loader && l.loader.search("sass-loader") !== -1) {
          l.options.sassOptions.importer = jsonImporter();
        }
        return l;
      });
      rule.use = transformedLoaders;
    }
  });
  return config;
};
```

I've been importing breakpoints originally created for angular flexlayout.

breakpoints.json

```
{
  "breakpoints": [
    {
      "alias": "xs",
// Notice the quoting
      "mediaQuery": "'screen and (min-width: 0px) and (max-width: 599.98px)'",
      "priority": 1000
    },
    ...
]
}
```

breakpoints.scss

```
@import "./breakpoints.json";

$bps: ();

// Reformat from json
@each $breakpoint in $breakpoints {
  $i: index($breakpoints, $breakpoint);
  $bps: map-merge(
    $bps,
    (
      map-get($breakpoint, alias): map-get($breakpoint, mediaQuery),
    )
  );
}

// Can be used with
// @media #{(map-get($bps, xs))} {
//      margin: 0 -15px;
//    }
```

breakpoints.ts

```
import { BreakPoint } from '@angular/flex-layout';

// Custom breakpoints
const brkpnts: BreakPoint[] = require('./breakpoints.json').breakpoints;
export const JSONBreakpoints = brkpnts.map((bp) => {
  // Remove the single qoutes needed for the sass variables
  return { ...bp, mediaQuery: bp.mediaQuery.substring(1).slice(0, -1) };
});
```

app.module.ts

```
import { JSONBreakpoints } from './breakpoints';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
FlexLayoutModule.withConfig({ disableDefaultBps: true }, JSONBreakpoints)
  ]
})
```