# React : webpack.config.js modification to import json variables in a sass file?

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I am trying to import variables from **.json** file in a **.scss** file with `node-sass-json-importer` package.

I am facing a problem because this package is not automatically integrated in `react-scripts/config/webpack.config.js`. So, I would like to modify this file as follows below :

1. Add `const jsonImporter = require ('node-sass-json-importer');`
2. Add an optional `preProcessorOptions` object parameter to getStyleLoaders function. Indeed, this function has no preprocessor options `const getStyleLoaders = (cssOptions, preProcessor)` and the only option added by default is `sourceMap: true`. Of course, this function will take in account this new parameter.
3. Add a third parameter in the getStyleLoaders call for scss file.

```
    {
      implementation: require("sass"),
      sassOptions: {
        importer: jsonImporter(),
      }
    }
```

It works on a minimal webpack implementation (without react). But, I suppose it is not so easy to apply changes to react-scripts/config/webpack.config.js and I suspect I will have many problems. Perhaps, there is an another way to do it. 
Thanks for answer.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60510735/angular-how-to-parse-json-variables-into-scss

Comment: @Mahdizoraghi. Thanks for answer but it concerns angular and not react