# Angular: Override bootstrap variable with dynamic variable (loaded from service)

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4

I probably got into deadend. I'm trying to override bootstrap scss `$primary` variable with own one that I load into a component through a service from external JSON config file (content of this file can vary).

The straightest solution that came to my mind was like this:

ComponentStyles.scss

```
$primary = {{variableLoadedFromConfigFile}};
```

Previous solution was static

```
$primary = blue;
```

and now I need to change it to dynamic behavior (in sense of loading that value from file).

Is this even possible?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you trying to override a material class or something like that? you need to provide more information, your question lacks information.

Comment: @Bargros I edited my question, hope it is more clear now.

Comment: Sorry I'm still not getting what you're trying to say, it sounds to me like you need to define your own palate, if so read this answer [create palate theme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41440998/how-can-i-use-custom-theme-palettes-in-angular)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end I solved it by loading values from `json` directly to `scss` with **node-sass-json-importer** as it is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60851939/4741929).

Answer (score 0):

The way I have found to inject custom CSS files at runtime is with `<link />` element inside my components.

An implementation of this is the above:

HTML

```
<link rel="stylesheet" [href]='cssUrl'>
```

TS

```
cssUrl: SafeResourceUrl;

constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {}

ngOnInit() {
  this.cssUrl = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(`assets/my.css`);
}
```

PS: You should put the file you want to inject inside your assets in the `Angular.json`.

PS2: Be aware of caching Issues.

*After Question Edited*

The *Angular* way to update dynamically CSS is using [NgStyle](https://angular.io/api/common/NgStyle) directive. Or to use HTML interpolation in  `[styles]`.

**You can not use interpolation in CSS files.**

You can also create CSS links like the example a gave you and insert custom CSS files or you can use a component without encapsulation to inject some CSS to the HTML body.

Comment: I'm afraid I wasn't clear enough. I do not need to load another css but load that variable from JSON and somehow insert it into styles.